# Does shards failure equivalent to loss of data in report generation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using kibana  above Elastic search. Where when i generate reprot in Kibana results in shards failure.
Do this result in less data fetch for the report.
How can we fix shards error in Elastic Search

Answer (score 0):

If one or more shards failed while request you get **only part** of data. 
To fix this problem more information needed. Probably you have some errors in logs of elasticsearch or shard failure reason.

Comment: [2018-05-25 08:55:11,600][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Bes] [prpc-alert-logs-2018.05.14][3], node[Q9ApxosdQnqMCRMmTw36Pw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@636784ec] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) on org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23@15e53da0
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsAbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(EsAbortPolicy.java:62)

Comment: May i request you to help me on this , it's something quite urgent now